# How to get data from other form that will display in combo box from other form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms and they are `Frm_Department` and `Frm_Employee`

How can I transfer data from my TextBox(`Frm_Department`) into ComboBox(`Frm_Employee`)? The image below this is where I will transfer the data from my `TextBox`.

Here are the forms.

[image]

Code of form department:

```
if (txtDepname.Text != "" && txtDepLocation.Text != "" && txtDepLocal.Text != "" )
{
    DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    tbldepartment dep = new tbldepartment();
    dep.DepID = txtDepID.Text;
    dep.Depname = txtDepname.Text;
    dep.Location = txtDepLocation.Text;
    dep.LocalPhone = txtDepLocal.Text;
    Insert.sp_insertdepartment(dep);
    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Saved!");
    AutoGenerate();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Input all Details....");
}
```

Code of form employee:

```
if (txtempLname.Text != "" && txtempFname.Text != "" && txtempMname.Text != "" && txtempPossition.Text != "")
{
    DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    tblemployee emp = new tblemployee();
    emp.EmpID = txtempnum.Text;
    emp.Lname = txtempLname.Text;
    emp.Fname = txtempFname.Text;
    emp.Mname = txtempMname.Text;
    emp.Position = txtempPossition.Text;
    Insert.sp_insertemployee(emp);
    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Saved!");
    AutoGenerate();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Input all Details....");
}
```

Comment: where is the other form? both links are the same

Comment: In form-to-form communication, you should use delegated events @Janny Janny

Comment: Why dont you use database to insert so the second form can fetch data from it?

Comment: Agreed with TAHA. It looks like you're inserting the values into the database. When you open the Employee form, reload the values.